# If you buy Modern Warfare digitally and insert a physical copy, how can you play the digital one again?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-modern-warfare

I bought the digital copy of modern warfare and my brother inserted the disc copy recently. Do I have to insert the disc again to play even though I bought it digitally?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar situation with Horizon Zero Dawn. If you uninstall the game from your device, then re-install digitally, should not ask for the disc again to launch.